# WCF Streaming issue with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, streaming, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service hosted in a ASP.NET application and am trying to upload a file from another client ASP.NET application using streaming mode.
I keep getting following error:

> The remote server returned an
>   unexpected response: (400) Bad
>   Request.

I have browsed the net to get help but to no avail.

**Host configuration:**

```
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="FileTransferServicesBinding"
          transferMode="Streamed"
          messageEncoding="Mtom"
          sendTimeout="01:05:00"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="10067108864">
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="FileTransferServiceBehavior" name="WebServiceHost.TransferService">
        <clear />
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="FileTransferServicesBinding" contract="WebServiceHost.ITransferService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
            <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange">
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:11291/TransferService.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="FileTransferServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Contracts code:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITransferService
{
    [OperationContract]
    RemoteFileInfo DownloadFile(DownloadRequest request);

    [OperationContract]
    void UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request);

    [OperationContract]
    string TestMethod();
}

[MessageContract]
public class DownloadRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string FileName;
}

[MessageContract]
public class RemoteFileInfo : IDisposable
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string FileName;

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public long Length;

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (FileByteStream != null)
        {
            FileByteStream.Close();
            FileByteStream = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Client configuration:**

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="FileTransferServicesBinding" sendTimeout="01:05:00"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="10067108864" messageEncoding="Mtom"
        transferMode="Streamed" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:11291/TransferService.svc/"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="FileTransferServicesBinding"
      contract="TransferServiceReference.ITransferService" name="FileTransferService"
      kind="">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
      <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
          x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Client code:

```
ITransferService clientUpload = new TransferServiceClient();

string datetime = clientUpload.TestMethod();

var uploadRequestInfo = new RemoteFileInfo();

uploadRequestInfo.FileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
uploadRequestInfo.Length = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
uploadRequestInfo.FileByteStream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
clientUpload.UploadFile(uploadRequestInfo);
```

The call fails for both clientUpload.TestMethod() and clientUpload.UploadFile(uploadRequestInfo). With buffered mode clientUpload.TestMethod() is invoked so the issue is with the configuration in the streaming mode.

I'd be grateful to find any help on this matter. Thanks.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with the config.  You may have to [Enable Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on the service to dig a bit deeper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the same problems and I found this article explain to solve your error. 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/BruceZhang/stream-operation-in-wcf/.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

Issue is in your data contract - `public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;`. Remove this member from data contract and use `stream` in your operation contract  - for example:

```
[OperationContract(OneWay=true)]
void UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request, System.IO.Stream fileData);
```

Quoted from [Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx) (MSDN):

> You should not be using
>   System.IO.Stream derived types inside
>   of data contracts. Stream data should
>   be communicated using the streaming
>   model, explained in the following
>   "Streaming Data" section.

Streaming Data section from the same link explains this in details.

Issue is in your data contract - `public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;`. Remove this member from data contract and use `stream` in your operation contract  - for example:

```
[OperationContract(OneWay=true)]
void UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request, System.IO.Stream fileData);
```

Quoted from [Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx) (MSDN):

> You should not be using
>   System.IO.Stream derived types inside
>   of data contracts. Stream data should
>   be communicated using the streaming
>   model, explained in the following
>   "Streaming Data" section.

Streaming Data section from the same link explains this in details.

EDIT:
Apologies - I have overlooked restrictions. You have two ways to solve the issue - use `MessageContract` or use multiple operations for a single transaction. Example of using multiple operations will be

```
[OperationContract]
Token UploadFile(System.IO.Stream fileData);

[OperationContract]
void ProvideFileInfo(Token token,  RemoteFileInfo request);
```

First upload the data to server and server will issue a token (e.g. guid), use the token to update other information.

More preferable way will be using `MessageContract` and which you have already trying. Few suggestions to trouble-shoot:

1. If your hosting it in IIS, check maxRequestLength in web.config. Try uploading small files.
2. Instead of using stream of PostedFile directly, store it to disk and use stream over it. Reasoning being  http request stream may getting cleaned up while upload is in progress.
3. Use tool such as fiddler and see message going over wire to the service, that may give a clue.

Comment: When Stream is used it imposes few restrictions:
There can only be one parameter or return value of stream type and if other type parameters are passed then the following error is thrown:
"System.InvalidOperationException: For request in operation UploadFile to be a stream the operation must have a single parameter whose type is Stream."

Comment: I also need to pass some data related to the stream, such as the identifying value and hence MessageContract was used. Again, when MessageContract is used on a single parameter is allowed.

Comment: FYI: Exception is thrown when void UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request, System.IO.Stream fileData); is used:
"The operation UploadFile either has a parameter or a return type that is attributed with MessageContractAttribute.  In order to represent the request message using a Message Contract, the operation must have a single parameter attributed with MessageContractAttribute.  In order to represent the response message using a Message Contract, the operation's return value must be a type that is attributed with MessageContractAttribute and the operation may not have any out or ref parameters."

Comment: [Restrictions on Streamed Transfers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx)

Comment: @rageit, apologies! - I have overlooked restrictions and your usage of `MessageContract` attribute. See my edit - see if those suggestions helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. Will try with fiddler and other updates again and will let you know later.